# Is there a word for the state of being just out of bed?

Tags: word-request

As the title implies, I'm looking for a word that results in the meaning of being in the state of "just out of bed", not concentrating and cannot talk regularly.
The usage would be something similar to `I'm sorry I didn't pickup the phone, I was still ____ and my mind was a bit fuzzy.`

Comment: I think the word you want is "groggy."

Comment: @SarahT Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any single word that specifically connotes "just out of bed".  *Discombobulated* doesn't have this connotation, and is rather playfully esoteric, which may not be appropriate, but it would fit your sentence and general meaning of being confused and 'not with it'.  *Groggy* is a more commonplace word which also suggests being slow and unable to think properly, but similarly, can refer to such a mental state not only after awakening, but also after injury or alcohol/drug intoxication.

Comment: This pretty much solves the problem. Thank you so much. :)